# Blazor Server - Refresh User Roles without Logging Out?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Say you're using the built in AspNetCore Identity implementation.

To access some data a User must have the "CanFetchData" role. If they don't, a "Get Access" button is displayed which upon being clicked gives the User the Role and now they can see the data. **Without Loggin Out**. That's all I'm trying to do.

So onclick we:

```
var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
var currUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(authState.User);
await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(currUser, "CanFetchData");
```

And now the Role is in the db. But the only way to update the view is to fully logout.

I've tried using StateHasChanged(); and SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(currUser) and a number of other approaches.
I realized that if I add the Claim directly it will update properly:

```
var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "CanFetchData"));
authState.User.AddIdentity(newIdentity);
```

**But is there no built in function to just refresh from the db?**

Comment: I'm afraid you have to update the session once you update the database, as user information is stored in session when user signs in. Only log out and log in again can make it auto update....

Comment: No.  The `AuthenticationStateProvider` builds the `ClaimsPrincipal` from the page header.  To refresh the header you need to reload the SPA session.  Adding the `ClaimsIdentity` to the existing `ClaimsPrincipal` is the right solution.